# Backbone.js + Handlebars.js - {{#each}} instead of model view?

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have a Collection called `Projects` that contains several models of type `Project`. When I want to list all the projects, I use a `ListProjectsView`. Its `render` function generates a `ProjectView` for each project in the collection, making it possible to delete one single project by binding an event to its name.

However, now I want to use Handlebars for creating templates. With handlebars it easier to display all the collection models, with the `each` helper, like this:

```
<ul>
  {{#each projects}}
  <li>{{this.name}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

This works fine but now I am wondering how can I delete one project, since I am not using `ProjectView` anymore. Do I need to add an `id` to each `<li>` so I can bind an event? Or do I have to use `ProjectView` to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

the logic here will have to run through ListProjectsView. One way is to do as you say and attach an `data-id` to each `li` and then in your event handler get the target

```
deleteProjectHandler : function(evt){
    var $target = $(evt.target), id = $target.data('id');

    this.deleteProject(id);
}
```

Or something of the like.

Comment: Is it a good practice to have the database id of an object in the DOM?

Comment: i don't see why not. it might as well be an arbitrary ID to users or anyone looking through the DOM